# What is a Formula for Risking 1% of Yesterday's Bankroll for all of Today's Bets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a hypothetical $10,000 starting bankroll.

I would like a formula to bet 1% of yesterday's ending bankroll for each of my daily bets.

For example, if my account ended at $100 the day before, then all of my bets today would be $1 (or 1% of $100).

The daily bet size for ALL of the bets that day should be 1% of the starting bankroll from the day prior. This value will be in the column **Last Bank**. Note **Last Bank** is the sum of all values in the **Outcome** column prior to today.

On Day 1 there were no days prior so **Last Bank** is Null for this day only.

Here is what my table looks like so far for DAY 1 prior to making any bets:

| Date | Risk | Outcome | Start Bank | Profit/Loss | Last BANK | Today |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 |  |  | 10,000 |  |  | 1/1/23 |

I am trying to find a formula for the **Risk** column. This formula works fine for day 1.

IF **Last Bank** = Null, **Risk** = **Start Bank** * .01... Else **Risk** = **Last Bank** *.01

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2), D2*.01, F2*.01
```

Here is the update table for **Risk** which tells me that 1% of my **Last Bank** is $100:

| Date | Risk | Outcome | Start Bank | Profit/Loss | Last Bank | Today |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | 100 |  | 10,000 |  |  | 1/1/23 |

Let's say I won the 1st bet 'WIN' and won $100 overall (+100 odds).

| Date | Risk | Outcome | Start Bank | Profit/Loss | Last Bank | Today |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | 100 | WIN | 10,000 | 100 |  | 1/1/23 |

Hopefully everything is straight forward so far. Just tryin to find the **Risk** value which is 1% of my starting bankroll from the day prior, **Last Bank**. On day 1 **Last Bank** is Null so **Risk** is 1% of the **Start Bank**.

This is the part that get's more tricky.

I can sum the **Outcome** values prior to today using this formula:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A, "<="&TODAY()-1, E2:E)
```

Now let's say we are on Day 2 (1/2/23) and I have two bets. We now have a $10,100 bankroll after yesterday's win... and the value for **Last Bank** has been filled in (10,000 + 100).

| Date | Risk | Outcome | Start Bank | Profit/Loss | Last Bank | Today |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | 100 | WIN | 10,000 | 100 | 10,100 | 1/2/23 |
| 1/2/23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/2/23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Again, I am trying to find the formula for **Risk**... but only if the dates match. For example A3=G2... or 1/2/23 (in Date column) = 1/2/23 (in Today column).

The key here is that I do not want the **Risk** value formula for the day prior (1/1/23) to change once the date changes. To be more clear, I do not want the **Risk** amount to change on 1/1/23 when there is a new day. The **Risk** values from days prior should stay the same.

On Day 2 I would like the **Risk** value for all rows where the **Date** equals **Today** to be 1% of $10,100. In other words...  If Date = Today, Risk = Last Bank * .01.

I would like All of the bets for 1/2/23 to bet 1% of the **Last Bank** or $101 (10,100 * .01).

| Date | Risk | Outcome | Start Bank | Profit/Loss | Last Bank | Today |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | 100 | WIN | 10,000 | 100 | 10,100 | 1/2/23 |
| 1/2/23 | 101 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/2/23 | 101 |  |  |  |  |  |

The formula I am looking for will fill in the two values in the table above with 101 in 2nd row, 1/2/23 and the 3rd row, also 1/2/23.

To reiterate what I am trying to do... I am trying to find a Risk formula that will tell me 1% of the **Last Bank** from the day prior so that each bet has the same bet % that day.

**Updated step** (by request)
Let's say I won both of the bets on 1/2/23 for simplicity... and that all bets are even money odds meaning you will get paid 100 for every winning bet $100 you risked.

In this case we risked $101 for each bet so we are now up $202 for the day ($101 + $101).

Now we are on Day 3.
The Last Bank is now at $10,302. Note the Last bank is the sum of the column Profit/Loss prior to today (see formula above for reference) plus the starting bankroll.

Since the Last Bank is $10,302 on the morning of 1/3/23, the new Risk is $103.2 for each of these two bets ($10,302 * .01).

| Date | Risk | Outcome | Start Bank | Profit/Loss | Last Bank | Today |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | 100 | WIN | 10,000 | 100 | 10,302 | 1/3/23 |
| 1/2/23 | 101 | WIN |  | 101 |  |  |
| 1/2/23 | 101 | WIN |  | 101 |  |  |
| 1/3/23 | 103.2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/3/23 | 103.2 |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Didn't you ask exactly this question yesterday? What happened to that?

Comment: Yes, but I did not add the dropdowns (and my question was likely confusing) so my question was taken down. Gave my question a facelift so hopefully it is easier to articulate. I understand there is a lot going on. I will continue working on this question, too, and will update if I find the answer first. Thanks! =)

Comment: @AbleArcher do you thing you can provide more sample data on your Sheet, for continuity and use cases purposes.

Comment: @Babanana, yes. I will add more in the next day or two. Ty!

Comment: @Babanana I added some more detail to my question. Please let me know if I need to add anything else for more clarity. Ty for your response!

Comment: @AbleArcher can you add data for day 3? Just to confirm this is how you exactly want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calculating a cell and not change previous values.

Though there is some confusion with your desired output. I think what you are looking at is just keeping the value regardless if the condition is not meant. I have replicated it on my end and this formula fixes it.

### Formula:

`If(A3 = $G$3, $F$3 *0.01, B3)`

Take note that in this formula I am assuming that B3 is your first cell (Risk Row) to apply this formula and A is where you put the Date where entry was made. G3 is where your current date and F3 is your Last Bank. The false statement in the formula to just keep the values if it is false means that you apply this on a null value it will go #REF error but will be changed once the formula is met.

(Please take note that you can use this as a reference but doesn't guarantee that it could simply just copy paste on your sheet due to lack of actual copy of your sheet. Please change it accordingly to your need).

### Reference:

[If Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Ty @Babanana for your time and patience. This answer was very helpful to me. I immediately made some significant progress with this project thanks to you. =)